# How can I pass model with sub-model list to Controller from Razor .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the models below

```
public class Param
{
   public string Code {get;set;}
   public dynamic Value {get;set;}
}

public class BaseModel
{
  public string Code
  public List<Param> Params
}
```

How should I use this model in Razor page, and how should I pass to controller view another Razor page?

The `Value` property of `Task` is dynamic. When the type is dynamic the value not get passed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class Param
{
   public string Code {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
}

public class BaseModel
{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public List<Param> Params { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model BaseModel 
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Code" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Code" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Code" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Params.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Params[i].Code" class="control-label">Params[@i].Code</label>
            <input asp-for="Params[i].Code" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Params[i].Code" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Params[i].Value" class="control-label">Params[@i].Value</label>
            <input asp-for="Params[i].Value" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Params[i].Value" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
            public IActionResult TestBaseModel()
            {
                BaseModel b = new BaseModel { Code = "b1", Params = new List<Param> { new Param { Code = "p1", Value = "1" }, new Param { Code = "p2", Value = "2" }, new Param { Code = "p3", Value = "3" } } };
                return View(b);
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult TestBaseModel(BaseModel b)
            {
                return View(b);
            }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Can you accept it as an answer?Thank you.

Comment: ur sample is work for string string Param model. but need for string dynamic Param model(my mistake :( ). so this answer not acceptable for me. But tnks mutch for your efforded times.

Comment: Why you need to `public dynamic Value {get;set;}`?

Comment: because param value may be date or integer or time or string[] int[] or etc array... etc... the type of param value will be several types.